# Defining two concurrent sets of differing page numbers

Tags: page-numbering

I have a reply brief and an opposition brief that must be consolidated.  The reply brief must not exceed 10 pages, and the opposition brief must not exceed 15 pages.  Every page must be consecutively numbered pursuant to court rules.  I would like to use additional sets of automatic page numbering in the footer to let the judge know that I have obeyed his guidelines and not exceeded my page limit.  Here is what I had in mind, but I need some help setting this up -- this is the bottom of every page:

```
                  -1-             Reply to Opposition [Page 1 of 10]
```

---

```
                  -2-             Reply to Opposition [Page 2 of 10]
```

---

```
                  -3-             Reply to Opposition [Page 3 of 10]
```

---

```
                                      * * *
```

---

```
                  -11-            Opposition to Motion [Page 1 of 15]
```

---

```
                  -12-            Opposition to Motion [Page 2 of 15]
```

---

```
                  -13-            Opposition to Motion [Page 3 of 15]
```

---

```
                                      * * *
```

Here is some sample code that handles the first part, but not the second part:

```
% BEGIN footer
\settitle{Reply to Opposition to R.F.O. -- page \thepage~of 10}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{\vspace{-1mm}\ptm{-\thepage-}}
\rfoot{\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill}\\
\mytitle}
% END footer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following provides a template for what you're after, assuming that you only have one reply-to-opposition/opposition-to-motion pair:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[abspage]{zref}
\usepackage{lipsum,pgffor}% Just for this example

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
\fancyfoot[C]{-\theabspage-\otherfooter}
\setcounter{abspage}{1}% Start absolute page numbering at 1

\newcommand{\otherfooter}{}

\newenvironment{Reply2Opposition}{%
  \clearpage
  \setcounter{page}{1}% Restart page numbering
  \renewcommand{\otherfooter}{%
    \qquad
    Reply to Opposition
    [Page \thepage~of~\pageref{replypage-end}]%
  }%
}{%
  \label{replypage-end}%
  \clearpage
}

\newenvironment{Opposition2Motion}{%
  \clearpage
  \setcounter{page}{1}% Restart page numbering
  \renewcommand{\otherfooter}{%
    \qquad
    Opposition to Motion
    [Page \thepage~of~\pageref{oppositionpage-end}]%
  }%
}{%
  \label{oppositionpage-end}%
  \clearpage
}

\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example

\begin{Reply2Opposition}
\foreach \replypage in {1,...,10} {
  \newpage\lipsum[\replypage]
}
\end{Reply2Opposition}

\begin{Opposition2Motion}
\foreach \oppositionpage in {1,...,15} {
  \newpage\lipsum[\oppositionpage]
}
\end{Opposition2Motion}

\end{document}
```

You would wrap each component of the document within a specific environment - either `Reply2Opposition` or `Opposition2Motion`. Each environment redefines the way the footer is constructed and uses a specific `\label` that references the last page of that section.

Fundamentally your setup has an `abs`olute `page` counter and a set of subsidiary page counters. We use the `abspage` module of [`zref`](//ctan.org/pkg/zref) to keep track of former, and adjust the traditional `page` counter to accommodate the separate component page number displays.